# init-system-helpers

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

Попытка установки vsftpd

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
vsftpd : Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~) but 1.14 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

LUBUNTU 14.04 на Orange Pi PC(v1.2). До этого делал update и upgrade. Как решить беду? Ждать пока не переведут пакет под arm? Скомпилить самому? Не ставить vsftpd?

```
root@orangepi:/home/jyree# apt-cache policy init-system-helpers
init-system-helpers:
  Installed: 1.14
  Candidate: 1.14
  Version table:
 *** 1.14 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.7~precise1~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teward/init-system-helpers/ubuntu/ precise/main armhf Packages

root@orangepi:/home/jyree# apt-cache policy vsftpd
vsftpd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.0.2-14
  Version table:
     3.0.2-14 0
        500 http://repo.ajenti.org/debian/ main/main armhf Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu2.14.04.1 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty-updates/main armhf
 Packages
     3.0.2-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ trusty/main armhf Packages
```

Comment: похоже на «кашу» из репозиториев. разберитесь в содержимом `/etc/apt/sources.list` и `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`.

Comment: С репами все нормально, вроде.

Comment: «вроде»? допустим. приложите тогда, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод команды `apt-cache policy init-system-helpers`. и, кстати, обновление списков пакетов и обновление самих пакетов вы давно выполняли последний раз?

Comment: Писал же, что только что сделал `apt-get update` и `apt-get upgrade`. "Обновление списка пакетов", вроде, тоже происходит при этом, не?

Comment: да, всё верно. «каша» уже видна: какой-то ppa с древней версией. но проблема не в нём, а в другом месте: осталось определить, откуда, из какой «каши» появился у вас кандидат для vsftpd со столь странными зависимостями. приложите, пожалуйста, вывод такой же команды и для пакета vsftpd.

Comment: добавил, видимо, он хочет ставить с ajenti репозитория

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас присутствуют в файлах `/etc/apt/sources.list`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` «лишние» репозитории.

если вы не считаете необходимым их удаление (после удаления надо будет обновить список пакетов командой `$ sudo apt-get update`), то можете (для данного случая) явно указать необходимую версию пакета. например, так (*пакет=версия*):

```
$ sudo apt-get install vsftpd=3.0.2-1ubuntu2
```

Comment: после удаления или закомментрования ссылки на репозиторий `apt-get update` делать не обязательно

Comment: в данном случае — обязательно. чтобы обновилось содержимое `/var/lib/apt/lists/` и *apt* не предлагал ставить пакеты из «удалённых/закомментированных» источников.

Comment: я сам много раз это пробовал, apt не ищет пакеты в закомментированных источниках, даже если они есть в `/var/lib/apt/lists/`